# Android OpenGL ES FPS optimization with big polygon amount

Tags: android, optimization, opengl-es, frame-rate

I'm drawing a 3d scene in 5-6 drawcalls, but I have about 60000-65000 triangles on the scene. LG optimus black has 13-14 fps, Lg optimus one has 10-12 fps and this is not cool.

Can I programmatically decrease triangle amount in models that are far away from camera? Or how else can I increase FPS?

Comment: All models are visible all the time? Any culling?

Comment: All models are always visible, gl_cull_face is enabled for everything except one rectangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is commonly known as level of detail or LOD. The most effective way of doing this on contemporary hardware is to offline author, either manually or programatically, several versions of the mesh with various triangle counts.